# Rotate a sprite to sprite position not exact in SpriteKit with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to rotate a player to the touch. Using the touches move function, I set the location to a variable. I then call a function. It works but the angle is off. Location is the global variable and player is the sprite I want to turn. It's off by about 15 degrees.

```
   func rotatePlayer(){

     let angle = atan2(location!.y - player!.position.y , location!.x - player!.position.x)
    player?.zRotation = angle
}
```

Comment: Which direction is your player facing when its `zRotation` is 0?

Comment: It's the default spaceship and the nose is facing up. zRotation is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SpriteKit Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html) doc

> Use game logic and art assets that match SpriteKit’s coordinate and rotation conventions. This means orienting artwork to the right. If you orient the artwork in some other direction, you need to convert angles between the conventions used by the art and the conventions used by SpriteKit.

Since the default spaceship points upward (when zRotation is 0), you will need to offset your angle by 90 degrees (pi/2 radians) so that the ship faces to the right when zRotation is zero:

```
player?.zRotation = angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2)
```

Alternatively, you can rotate the spaceship to the right. To rotate the image, click on Assets.xcassets and then click on Spaceship. Right click on the Spaceship image and select the Open in External Editor menu item. This will open the image in the Preview app. In Preview, select Tools > Rotate Right and quit Preview. By rotating the artwork, your code should work without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
//set sprite to image



Person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person")




    //set size
    Person.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 7)



    //set position
    Person.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 120)





    //rotate node 3.14 / 2 = to 90 degree angle
    Person.zRotation = 3.14 / 2



    Person.zPosition = 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an orientation constraint to rotate your object to the touch position:

```
// Create two global Sprite properties:

var heroSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
var invisibleControllerSprite = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {         

   // Create the hero sprite and place it in the middle of the screen
   heroSprite.xScale = 0.15
   heroSprite.yScale = 0.15
   heroSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
   self.addChild(heroSprite)

   // Define invisible sprite for rotating and steering behavior without trigonometry
   invisibleControllerSprite.size = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
   self.addChild(invisibleControllerSprite)

   // Define a constraint for the orientation behavior
   let rangeForOrientation = SKRange(constantValue: CGFloat(M_2_PI*7))

   heroSprite.constraints = [SKConstraint.orientToNode(invisibleControllerSprite, offset: rangeForOrientation)]

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */        
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        // Determine the new position for the invisible sprite:
        // The calculation is needed to ensure the positions of both sprites 
        // are nearly the same, but different. Otherwise the hero sprite rotates
        // back to it's original orientation after reaching the location of 
        // the invisible sprite
        var xOffset:CGFloat = 1.0
        var yOffset:CGFloat = 1.0
        var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if location.x>heroSprite.position.x {
            xOffset = -1.0
        }
        if location.y>heroSprite.position.y {
            yOffset = -1.0
        }

        // Create an action to move the invisibleControllerSprite. 
        // This will cause automatic orientation changes for the hero sprite
        let actionMoveInvisibleNode = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(location.x - xOffset, location.y - yOffset), duration: 0.2)
        invisibleControllerSprite.runAction(actionMoveInvisibleNode)

        // Optional: Create an action to move the hero sprite to the touch location
        let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: 1)
        heroSprite.runAction(actionMove)

    }

}
```

Tutorial: http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2014/11/how-to-implement-space-shooter-with.html

Video: https://youtu.be/8d8MH_gXt84

Comment: I've updated the sample code in my answer with a simpler solution

Comment: Do we really need to use a constraint? Can we just accurately find the angle and automatically set the angle of the player?

Comment: I think this is possible as well. But I don't know how. Had the same issue as you and gave up the calculation approach

Comment: My code plus the selected answer actually works. It's a lot less code as well.