# Moving Sprite properly based on the touch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a very simple app. I have squares falling from the sky, which are physics bodies. When the user taps an square, it jumps up. He needs to prevent the fruits from touching the ground.

Now I thought when touching the apple, just move its `position.y += 10`. But I would like the apple to jump up in different x-directions as well and I dont know how to implement that.

For example when I touch the bottom left edge of the square, it should not only jump up but an decent amount to the right as well.

Any ideas how to implement this moving into swift?

Comment: check this answer and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016756/swift-spritekit-rotate-sprite-in-the-direction-of-touch/38017316#38017316

Comment: thank you but not what I was searching for. I am trying to "kick" the spirte nodes as if you would juggle a soccer ball.

Answer (score 3):

As you already have PhysicsBodies, you can use the [applyImpulse(_:,at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520407-applyimpulse) to apply a 'bump' to the object when touched. Set the vector to be upwards and the position to be the position of the touch (in the object's coordinates).

Alternatively, for more control, use [applyImpulse(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519900-applyimpulse), set the vector of the impulse to mostly upward with a bias left or right according to the X position of the touch to give it the push left or right you are looking for. Then for additional realism you could [applyAngularImpulse(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520122-applyangularimpulse) at the same time to give it some spin.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for. Imagine i have a ball. when you touch it exactly in the middle, it bumps straight upwards. but when you touch it in the bottom left corner it will bump slightly to the right, as you "kicked" it on the bottom left. Using applyImpulse helped bumping it, but only straight upwards. And I would like to avoid just using a biased left or right `dy:` because it should jump on a side based on the bottom corner you touched. but thank you very much for your afford sir.

Comment: @JushKillaB you are not using applyimpulse correctly then.  use atan2 to calculate the angle between the point you are touching and the center of the ball, then use vector = x:  m * cos(angle), y: m* sin(angle) (Providing that 0 degrees lies on the right part of the x axis) where m is the magnitude of your force