# Node rotation in Scenekit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Im having trouble figuring out how to rotate my player node towards each click.  Ive already got the intercept of a click on the x-z plane and set the node to move to it, and I have found out the radians of the click compared to the plane of x and z on which the character moves.  After the character isn't at 0 y rotation my method doesn't work though.  Im guessing theres an easier way to do this, just hoping someone can point me to some documentation or tell me what way I can figure out the difference between the clicks angle and the current orientation of the player and make him face towards the movement.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if game.state == .tapToPlay {
        startGame()
    }

    if game.state == .playing {

        let touch = touches.first!
        let location = touch.location(in: scnView)
        let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

        if hitResults.first?.node.name == "Grass" {
            //pigNode.runAction(SCNAction.move(to: (hitResults.first?.localCoordinates)!, duration: 1.0))
            let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: (hitResults.first?.localCoordinates)!, duration: 1.0)
            let location = hitResults.first?.localCoordinates

            /*
            pigNode.runAction(SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0.0,
                                                 y: CGFloat(offset.y),
                                                 z: 0.0, duration: 1.0, usesShortestUnitArc: true))

            let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: CGFloat((locationOnPlane?.x)!),
                                                  y: CGFloat((locationOnPlane?.y)!),
                                                  z: CGFloat((locationOnPlane?.z)!),
                                                  duration: 1.0, usesShortestUnitArc: true)
            */
            let locationOnPlane = CGPoint(x: Double((location?.x)!), y: Double((location?.z)!))
            let offset = CGPoint(x: Double(locationOnPlane.x) - Double(pigNode.position.x), y: Double(locationOnPlane.y) - Double(pigNode.position.z))
            let length = sqrt(offset.x * offset.x + offset.y * offset.y)
            let direction = CGPoint(x: offset.x / length, y: offset.y / length)

            let rotationAngle = CGFloat(atan2(direction.y, direction.x))

            let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotate(by: rotationAngle, around: SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0), duration: 1.0)
            //let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0.0, y: rotationAngle, z: 0.0, duration: 1.0)
            //let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0.0, y: rotationAngle, z: 0.0, duration: 1.0, usesShortestUnitArc: true)

            print(rotationAngle)
            print(pigNode.eulerAngles.y)



            let groupAction = SCNAction.group([moveAction, rotateAction])
            pigNode.runAction(groupAction)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think I figured it out.  The way I'm calculating the angles on the X Z plane, Z is actually X if it were an X Y plane since when the node is facing along that axis it is an angle of 0.  So I just changed locationOnPlane.x to locations z value and then used the rotateAction thats commented out which has the uses shortest unit arc on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [Rotate a sprite to sprite position not exact in SpriteKit with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113657/rotate-a-sprite-to-sprite-position-not-exact-in-spritekit-with-swift?rq=1) this is the code for rotation

```
let angle = atan2(location.y - cannon.position.y , location.x - cannon.position.x)
 cannon.zRotation = angle - CGFloat(M_PI_2)
```

I hope this helps you